# Displaying data from mysql in onchange of selection is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two php files stockentry.php and getuser.php
I want to display the details from mysql tabel in onchange of selection
I called the getuser.php in onchange
But no result
Please Help
Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction(str) {

  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    // window.alert(str)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check the xhr in the browser's dev tools. Press F12, then go to the Console tab. (On Firefox, make sure the XHR button at the top of the console is enabled.) Now call your function and check the request.

Comment: You need to debug it yourself step by step using the browser's inspection tools. How can we know what is wrong without working on your computer? You need to verify if AJAX request is done, if the response is sent, and if it has a valid format and has no errors. That work cannot be done remotely until you'll grant remote access to your desktop to someone.